# How to use Snackbar in a relative layout instead of Toasts?

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I am trying to use Snackbar instead of Toasts in a relative layout to display the error (If input field are empty). But I am unable to add the snackbar in place of Toast.

Below is my code for Toasts -

```
if (abc_value.equals("") || def_value.equals("") || ghi_value.equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), next.class);
```

If any of the 3 fields are empty, it will display the string message else it will navigate to next activity.

EDIT -

1. 1st try :

   ```
   Snackbar.make(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), "Test", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   ```

This didn't as it wan't accepting the rootview - I felt this was the closest.

2. ```
   Snackbar.make(findViewById(Ids), "Test", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                           .setAction("Undo", mOnClickListener)
                           .setActionTextColor(Color.RED)
                           .show();
   ```

Tried using ID but it didn't accept.

3. ```
   Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
       .make(coordinatorLayout, "Welcome to AndroidHive", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

   snackbar.show();
   ```

Cannot use this as I am not using the coordinatorLayout.

Comment: did you at least try to google for: `android snackbar`?

Comment: You know that you **have to** search before asking, right?

Comment: @pskink Without googling, I wouldn't have come here. I've mentioned that what I am doing, hope that is satisfactory

Comment: Well, As all of you are mentioning that I haven't done ANY research on this, I am editing my question and will add what I have used before coming here :)

Comment: @AbhishekDS the code you have provided does not have a `Snackbar` class uses . I suggest when working with new classes in android take a first look at it At https://developer.android.com/.

Comment: For all of you who blindly came up with comments that I didn't try using Snackbar before coming here, Please check the updated question. Meanwhile, @pskink Thanks for your time in demotivating someone :)

Comment: I Hope now you can remove your down-vote @ADM

Comment: I Hope now you can remove your down-vote @VladyslavMatviienko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
    .make("id of root layout", "content of displayed message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

snackbar.show();
```

Comment: That is it. Updated your answer in order to clear the confusion of the ID to be used :)

Comment: my answer is same yourMainLayout :(

Comment: @propoLis, no, your answer is better, since it is a *complete* working code as opposed to this answer where author uses `"id of your root layout control"` (whatever it means) - i have no idea why it is the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
     if (abc_value.equals("") || def_value.equals("") || ghi_value.equals("")) {

            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(yourMainLayout, 
            "Please enter all fields!", Snackbar. LENGTH_SHORT);

            // Changing action button text color
            View sbView = snackbar.getView();
            TextView textView = (TextView) 
            sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            snackbar.show();
        }

        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), next.class);
        }
```

Comment: You have posted an answer which is related to usage of coordinatorLayout which is not being used as I have mentioned in the details of the question.

Comment: coordinatorLayout is your main layout which is relativeLayout, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside `if`

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "your error", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.show();
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol root layout is what I am getting when I tried this!

Comment: rootLayout means your activity's main layout.

Comment: Even if I replace that with RelativeLayout, it shows the same error

Comment: You have to first make a relative layout instance like Relativelayout relative; and then findViewById() it.

Comment: I used the class name and it worked instead of finding it by relative layout.